# Retrofit Doesnt show nested arraylists

Tags: android, json, arraylist, gson, retrofit

I am trying to download data from the url ( JSON ) = 
https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json

for the networking i have used retrofit, and these are my classes, whenever i try to access the nested classes or lists, it throws a fatal error.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Recipe> mRecipies = new ArrayList<>();
public TextView text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    IRecipe iRecipe = RetrofitBuilder.Retrieve();
    Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> recipe = iRecipe.getRecipe();

    recipe.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Recipe>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> call, Response<ArrayList<Recipe>> response) {
            mRecipies = response.body();
            text.setText(mRecipies.get(3).getIngredients().size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

MyRecipe class

```
public class Recipe {

private String id;
private String name;
private List<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Steps> steps = new ArrayList<>();
private String servings;

public Recipe(String id, String name,  String servings, List<Ingredients> ingredients, List<Steps> steps) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.steps = steps;
    this.servings = servings;
}

public Recipe(){

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Ingredients> getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}

public void setIngredients(List<Ingredients> ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

public List<Steps> getSteps() {
    return steps;
}

public void setSteps(List<Steps> steps) {
    this.steps = steps;
}

public String getServings() {
    return servings;
}

public void setServings(String servings) {
    this.servings = servings;
}
```

}

My ingredients class

```
public class Ingredients  {

private String quantity;
private String measure;
private String ingredient;


public Ingredients(String quantity, String measure, String ingredient) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.measure = measure;
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
}

public Ingredients(){

}


public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getMeasure() {
    return measure;
}

public void setMeasure(String measure) {
    this.measure = measure;
}

public String getIngredient() {
    return ingredient;
}

public void setIngredient(String ingredient) {
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
}
```

}

Retrofit classes

Builder

```
        public final class RetrofitBuilder {
        static IRecipe iRecipe;

        public static IRecipe Retrieve() {

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();


            iRecipe = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .callFactory(httpClientBuilder.build())
                    .build().create(IRecipe.class);


            return iRecipe;
        }
    }


Interface 

    public interface IRecipe {
    @GET("baking.json")
    Call<ArrayList<Recipe>> getRecipe();
}
```

Stack Trace

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.vamshi.retrofittrial, PID: 20350
                                                                              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:328)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:123)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4432)
                                                                                  at com.example.vamshi.retrofittrial.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

07-08 19:07:00.145 20350-20350/com.example.vamshi.retrofittrial E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `setText` doesnt allow integers.

So instead of

```
text.setText(mRecipies.get(3).getIngredients().size());
```

use

```
text.setText(String.valueof(mRecipies.get(3).getIngredients().size()));
```